# Redis starts slowly when aof file is too large

Tags: redis

Redis starts slowly when aof file is too large.The aof file is still large after rewriting.How to deal with it?

We can not close aof  and we need start redis up quickly

Answer (score 0):

> The aof file is still large after rewriting

That means your data set is really large.

In order to accelerate restart, you can do persistence with RDB file. It should be faster to load RDB file than AOF file.

Also you can try to split your big data set into several small Redis instances, or move your data to Redis Cluster, so that each node has a smaller data set, and the reload work runs faster.

Comment: We deploy it on the industrial personal computer, and power will be cut off at any time. RDB can easily lead to data loss.We don't allow data loss.We can't deploy multiple Redis.

Comment: You have to trade-off these stuffs. B.T.W even with AOF, you might get data loss.

Comment: This is really annoying。We will seriously consider this problem。Thank you for your answer.